# How to XOR two byte streams in C?

Tags: c, xor

I've been reading through SO for the past couple of days trying to figure this out, I am stumped.  I want to read in two 32 bit byte arrays (from stdin, input will be hex) and xor them, then print the result.

So far I've tried using scanf, fgets, and gets.  My thought was to read the large hex numbers into a char buffer and perform the xor in a for loop until I hit an EOL (with fgets) or a null terminator.  So far my output is not even close.  I tried lots of variations, but I will only post my latest fail below.  The challenge I've been trying to complete is: http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/2/

I am trying it in C because I'm really trying to learn C, but I'm really getting frustrated with none of these attempts working.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char buff1[100];
    char buff2[100];
    char buff3[100];
    int size = sizeof(buff1);

    puts("Enter value\n");
    fgets(buff1, size, stdin);
    puts(buff1);
    puts("Enter value\n");
    fgets(buff2, size, stdin);
    puts(buff2);

    for (int i = 0; i != '\n'; i++) {
        buff3[i] = buff2[i] ^ buff1[i];
        printf("%x", buff3[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to convert the HEX string to a byte array first, than you can XOR them.

Comment: Did you do the first challenge from that website?

Comment: Yes, it was much more difficult because I didn't use a prebuilt b64 library.  I ended up with something similar to the C implementation of this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using sizeof() it should be used with types, not data. For instance if you want space for 100 chars, you need to find the sizeof(char) and then multiply by 100 to find out how many bytes you need and that goes into the buffer. A char is usually a byte so expect 100 bytes. fgets() will work but I prefer to use this

```
int getchar()
```

Just stop when the the user
enters a newline/terminator character. Since you don't know how many characters will come in from stdin, you
need to dynamically increase the size of your buffer or it will overflow. For the purposes of this question you can just make it a very big array, check to see if its about to overflow and then terminate the program. So to recap the steps.

1.) Create a big array

2.) While loop over getchar() and stop when the output is the terminator, take note of
how many chars you read.

3.) Since both buffers are guaranteed to have equal chars make your
final array equal to that many chars in size.

4.) For loop over getchar() and as the chars come out, xor them with the first array
and put the result into the final array. You should try doing this with 1 array
afterwards to get some more C practice.

Good luck!

EDIT:

fgets() can be used but depending on the implementation it is useful to know how many chars have been read in.

Comment: *Don't* use `char *gets(char *s)` for input. It is no longer part of the language standard library as of C11, with good reason. it is vile, evil, and a buffer-overflow attack in-wait. Use `fgets()` as the OP's code does. And `sizeof(char)` is *always* **1**. (the number of *octets* in a `char` is implementation defined, but is nearly always also 1).

Comment: `fgets()` is meant for files, I would just toss a wrapper around `getchar()` to get the same functionality. And yes `sizeof(char)` is always 1 but it was said in contrast to what the OP put. For a new c coder it would be good to see how `sizeof()` works. In practice it is good to be explicit. With the use of `sizeof(char)`, it provides uniformity and numbers won't be so ambiguous.

Comment: I concur with the reasons for using `sizeof(char)` namely consistency and good habits. And `fgets()` is meant for `FILE*`, which is not always an on-disk file (ex: `stdin`). *Anyone* that proliferates using `gets()` in this day and age needs their head examined, and it shocks me academia across the pond continues to teach it as-practice. The standards committee treads carefully in removing a standard library function, but that one was so bad they felt compelled to. The code that breaks with its removal is, by definition, an exploit in-wait, which removing it was precisely designed to stop.

Comment: `gets()` is definitely bad practice but it's thrown in for a complete answer. I wasn't even aware it was removed. But that's why I advised using `getchar()` and specifically mentioned buffer overflows.

Comment: Thanks for all the input on fgets vs getchar.  With sizeof(char), what you're saying makes a lot of sense.  I didn't realize I had to explicitly provide the buffer size in the multiplication, but it makes sense.  Would I be better to just set an int to the number of dynamically allocated (malloc'd) bytes that I use for my input buffer?  Thanks again!

Comment: No probs, for this problem there is no need to use malloc since you stay within the same function but yes you should keep that kind of information in a variable for overflow information. But it doesn't translate into the number of elements unless the malloc'd buffer is full so don't use it as a loop counter. Let me know if you haven't finished this problem yet and I'll give you some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static inline unsigned char hc2uc(char d){
    const char *table = "0123456789abcdef";
    return strchr(table, tolower(d)) - table;
}

...

for(int i=0;buff1[i]!='\n';i++){
    buff3[i]=hc2uc(buff2[i])^hc2uc(buff1[i]);
    printf("%x",buff3[i]);
}
```

Comment: Very non-user-friendly + pretty inefficient

Comment: Much simpler version for hc2uc: `return (d <= '9') ? d - '0' : toupper(d) - '0' - 7;`

Comment: Only if you have non-ASCII charset.

Comment: @icepack It does not become an excuse.

Comment: It's not an excuse, it's a question of need. Your code, for example, won't necessary compile in a freestanding environment (which is much more common than non-ASCII charset).

Comment: @icepack Did is written somewhere and are based on the assumption ASCII code? Do Standard of C   say what?

Comment: I never argued it's not portable to non-ASCII.

Comment: code for the character isn't specified in the standard C . It is not predetermined Also in this question. Are evaluated portability is low such programs depends on the character code it is of course.

Comment: It is possible to use something like the following be effective if is needed than it. pre-create the table,  such as (e.g) `table['a']` returned  `10`.